# How can I pass configure options to phpenv install

Tags: php

I'd like to install PHP via [phpenv](https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv) with ZTS and debug symbols enabled. In a manual install, I'd do this by passing [`--enable-debug` and `--enable-maintainer-zts`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.environment.php) to the configure options.

How can I pass these options to phpenv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typing `phpenv install --help` prints

```
Usage: phpenv install [--ini|-i <environment>] <version>
       phpenv install [--ini|-i <environment>] <definition-file>
       phpenv install -l|--list
       phpenv install -V|--version

 -l/--list     List all available versions
 -V/--version  Show version of php-build

For detailed information on installing PHP versions with
php-build, including a list of environment variables for adjusting
compilation, see: https://github.com/php-build/php-build
```

So there is no command line flag to pass these options. But the last paragraph redirects to https://github.com/php-build/php-build, which is what phpenv uses to install php. The readme in that repo isn't listing any environment variables, but digging into the [source code](https://github.com/php-build/php-build/blob/master/bin/php-build) and [the man files](https://github.com/php-build/php-build/tree/master/man) reveals the following:

> ### ENVIRONMENT
>
> - `PHP_BUILD_DEBUG`, set this to `yes` to trigger a `set -x`
>     call. This echo's all issued shell commands of the script.
> - `PHP_BUILD_XDEBUG_ENABLE=on|off` (default: `on`), set to `off` to comment out the
>     lines which enable XDebug, in the generated `xdebug.ini`.
> - `PHP_BUILD_CONFIGURE_OPTS`, list of additional configure options.
> - `PHP_BUILD_ZTS_ENABLE=on|off` (default: `off`), enables Zend Thread Safety for builds
> - `PHP_BUILD_INSTALL_EXTENSION` see [EXTENSION] section.

So to install PHP with ZTS and debug mode, one needs to use

```
PHP_BUILD_ZTS_ENABLE=yes \
PHP_BUILD_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-debug" \
phpenv install 7.1.0
```